# Transction Fees in erc20 smart contract

Tags: solidity

I ran into an issue...

I built a erc20 smart contract but dont know how to add features such as a transaction fees on each transaction.

How to code a transaction fees on each transaction?

Comment: see https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-20/
and go through openzeppelin

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're asking - but if you want to take a cut of the transaction whenever an ERC20 is transferred you could do this:.

In the ERC20 contract: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

Add owner to state, and update the constructor to be:

```
address contractDeployer;
uint txCharge = 1 // As we can't store decimals (1 = 1%)

constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
  _name = name_;
  _symbol = symbol_;
  contractDeployer= msg.sender;
}
```

Then, modify the transfer function to be:

```
function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
  address owner = _msgSender();
  // Transfers 1% of the amount to send to the contract deployer (you)
  _transfer(owner, contractDeployer, amount * txCharge / 100); 
  // Transfers the remaining 99% to the actual recipient
  _transfer(owner, to, amount - (amount * txCharge/100);
  return true;
}
```